# Why present tense in 'depuis que je suis petite'?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

I understand that in the main  clause of 'depuis que', present tense is used if the action is still ongoing, and that usually in the sub clause of 'depuis que', past tense is used.

- Depuis que je **suis revenue** [***past***] de ce voyage, je ne **fais** [***present***] que manger et dormir.

However what I can't understand is why present tense 'suis' is used below although the state of being a child is no longer true.

- Je **suis** [***present***] une passionnée depuis que je **suis** [***present***] petite.

Why is it wrong to say in past tense 'depuis que j'étais petite'?

- Je **suis** [***present***] une passionnée depuis que j'**étais** [***past***] petite.

Comment: The use of that present in the second sentence is an annoying illogicality, isn't it?

Comment: You might want to opt for a solution that makes use of no verb instead (2nd sentence), almost as in the English "I have  been passionate since my childhood .": "Je suis une passionnée  depuis mon enfance.".

Comment: The present tense (action verb or stative verb) verb in French followed by depuis is translated as a present perfect or present perfect continuous. For example: J'étudie depuis deux heures. I've been studying for two hours. I've loved this since I was a child. Je suis une passionnée de x  depuis que je suis petite.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether the subordinate clause (i.e. after *depuis que* ) is still true or not, the present used in the main clause (*manger et dormir* or *être une passionnée*) forbids the imperfect to be used in the subordinate clause  because the **main** action is still ongoing:

> I have been eating and sleeping since I came back from that trip.
>
> I have been a fan since I was a child.

You only use the imperfect in the subordinate clause when the main action happened in the past:

> *Je ne faisais que manger et dormir depuis que j'étais revenue de ce voyage*. (but this period is over)
>
> *Depuis que j'étais petite, j'étais une passionnée*. (this might have changed)

As you noticed, both the *passé composé* or *the present* are possible in the subordinate.

The *passé composé* is used when the period is relative while the present is used when the period is absolute, e.g.:

> *Depuis que j'ai passé mon permis, c'est moi qui conduit.* (relative, I passed it one day)
>
> *Depuis que j'ai le permis, c'est moi qui conduit.* (absolute, I still have it)

Both *je suis revenue* and *je suis petite* are telling from when the main clause is ongoing. Using the *passé composé* with *être petite* would insist on the fact this is no more true but is a little heavy:

> *Depuis que j'ai été petite, je suis une passionnée.*

The present is used instead as *être petite* is not a point in time but more a "permanent" state, although I understand how confusing it is for non native speakers.

The present can be used in similar situations where it wouldn't make sense in English:

> *Depuis que j'ai quatorze ans, j'aime le rock !*: The person talking is no more 14.
>
> *On le connaît depuis qu'il marche à quatre pattes*: He isn't toddling anymore.

If the subordinate describes a real point in time, the *passé composé* is used:

> *Depuis que j'ai fêté mes quatorze ans, j'aime le rock !*
>
> *On le connaît depuis qu'il a marché à quatre pattes pour la première fois.*

See [this Monique L'Huillier's document](https://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_1999_num_80_1_3567) that tells the tense mismatch between French and English is an issue for people learning French and [that Gabriel Wyler's page](http://gabrielwyler.com/page307.html) for a description of *depuis* uses, from which I picked the relationship between passé composé/present and relative/absolute.

Comment: Well, you could say "Je suis fan des des États-unis depuis que j'ai visité New York" : present used in the main, past in the subordonate.  I can't put my finger on the reason why though. *Question 3* in your link could be helpful but doesn't provide much info. Isn't that all very specific to the whole "depuis que je suis petit(e)" idiom ?

Comment: Yes, I corrected my answer. *Present* or *passé composé* are possible but not *imparfait*.

Comment: @LaurentS. Now you mention it (*seeing it as a fixed idiom*), what's your take on: "*Depuis que je **suis** petit, j'**étais** toujours attiré par tout ce qui touche à l'astronomie, (mais je ne le suis plus.)*"

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Doesn't work for me. That should be either *depuis que je suis petit, je suis attiré...* (still true) or *depuis que j'étais petit, j'étais attiré...* (no more true).

Comment: In addition to jlliagre, you could use "Depuis que j'étais petit, j'avais toujours été attiré par...". Note that you could maybe more elegantly convey the same meaning with less complex conjugation using "Depuis l'enfance, j'étais/j'avais été attiré"...